# Android accelerometer

Tags: java, android, accelerometer

I gathered plenty of samples and tutorials on the matter but once I implement my own version or even just copy the code straight off, I cannot get any values to show up in my log.

I think I am missing one important part but I cannot seem to figure it out.

```
public class Accelerometer extends Activity {

    SensorManager sensorManager;
    Sensor accelerometer;

    private SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

        }

        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

            float x = event.values[0];
            float y = event.values[1];
            float z = event.values[2];
            update(x, y, z);
        }
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    }

    public void update(float x, float y, float z) {

        Log.v("semajhan", "x: " + x + " y: " + y + " z: " + z);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensorEventListener);
    }
}
```

My problem seems to be that I do not know how to really access the accelerometer.

Once I can get these values, I can move forward but I need to understand this first.

Comment: The code looks good. The only thing I never used is the Log.v line. For the test you could add Toasts in several places in the code to make sure things are executing.

Comment: look this tutorial to know how android accelerometer works http://www.quicktips.in/get-accelerometer-readings-android/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems ok to me. It is similar to working examples I also used to fetch the sensor data. One thing may be problematic. Are you sure you have sensor of that type on your device?

To check that use

```
public List<Sensor> getSensorList (int type)
```

function of `SensorManager`. You can get full list of sensors available on your device if you use `type = Sensor.TYPE_ALL` in function call, and go through all list elements.

UPDATE:

Tried your code. It is fully functional. Issue is that display of traces is disabled on your Nexus. To enable traces go to Settings->Applications->Development and check option USB debugging. Without that you get no traces.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have Nexus One.

Comment: Devices do not have all sensors listed in SensorManager list. To see if your device has requested sensor, you may obtain list of available sensors using described approach. However, since you are using Nexus One, that should not be problem. I tested code snippets for sensors provided by Android SDK, and it worked correctly for the accelerometer on the Nexus One. So, strange issue.

Comment: My project is compiling and running well with no problems, it's just that it does not log anything. I assumed it would keep logging whenever I rotated my device in different angles which I, again, assumed would call the onSensorChanged method.

Comment: rotating the device is a SENSOR.TYPE_ORIENTATION event not Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER

Comment: So, if I wanted to get information on how my phone is rotated along the axis I would use ORIENTATION?

Comment: Definitely. Works fine as well on Nexus One.

Comment: That's what I would check first. Accelerometer is something I would use if I want to detect when the phone is shaken.